# How to subscribe to observable in the parent model from a component in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working with some legacy code that uses Knockout.js and I have to add a new functionality and I am a bit lost at one point. I can not share the actual code so I will use some pseudo code to describe my problem

Assume I have some sample View model

```
function ViewModel(params) 
  {
    this.questions = params.questions;
    this.clear = ko.observable();
  }
```

which gets an array of questions from external source but it is not an observable array. I also have a function in the View model which populates the clear() observable

```
ViewModel.prototype.add = function()
{
  if (this.clear === 'No'){
    this.clear('Yes');
   } else{
    this.clear('No');
   }
}
```

I have a registered component

```
ko.components.register('customComponent', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.clearInComponent = ko.observable(params.clear);
  },
  template: '<div data-bind="text: clearInComponent "></div>'
});
```

Now in my HTML I have a button which on click sets some value to cthe clear() observable and the component where I am passing the parameters from the View model

```
<button data-bind="click: add"></button>

<questionnaire params="questions: questions, clear:clear"></questionnaire>
```

Now whenever the value of clear() in the parent ViewModel is changed it is reflected as well in the component which is expected.
What I want to achieve is to set a subscription to clearInComponent so when the clear() observable in the parent View model changes I would be able to catch the event and do some additional things. I tried to add subscription to clearInComponent in the component View model but it does not work.

```
this.clearInComponent.subscribe = function(newValue){
   // do stuff
}
```

My question is if that is possible and how I can do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the issue:

```
this.clearInComponent = ko.observable(params.clear);
```

Since `params.clear` is itself an observable, you're basically wrapping an observable in another observable, making subscribing to `this.clearInComponent` useless since its value will never mutate.

Instead, just use `params.clear` directly:

```
this.clearInComponent = params.clear;

this.clearInComponent.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    // this should work fine...
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try it and post the result